# Maven command to determine which settings.xml file Maven is using

Tags: maven, command-line, maven-2, settings

How do I use maven command line to determine which settings.xml file Maven is picking up?

Answer (score 440, accepted):

Start maven with -X option (debug) and examine the beginning of the output. There should be something like this:

```
...
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from c:\....\apache-maven-3.0.3\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from c:\....\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\....\repository
...
```

(Original directory names are removed by me)

Comment: Perhaps this wasn't in the debug output until maven 3 was released, but your post some 2.5 years later is finally the exact answer I was looking for (sorry for the 6 month delay in noticing it).

Comment: The version of maven I was using, maven2.x, did not show this important detail when the -B flag was used. ... Unfortunate, if you're trying to debug what is going on with a Jenkins server.

Comment: I got a lot of output from `mvn -X`, which quickly scrolled beyond the buffer (on Windows) .Resolved by using `mvn -X |more` instead followed by CTRL+C to end the output.

Comment: And if you don't want to scroll through all the output you can grep for the settings like: ```mvn help:effective-settings -X | grep "settings from"```.Or using PowerShell: ```mvn help:effective-settings -X | Select-String "settings from"```.

Answer (score 204):

You can use the [maven help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) to tell you the contents of your user and global settings files.

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

will ask maven to spit out the **combined global and user settings**.

Comment: It helps to me updating old maven repo http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ to http://search.maven.org

Answer (score 193):

Your comment to cletus' (correct) answer implies that there are multiple Maven settings files involved.

Maven always uses either one or two settings files. The **global settings** defined in (`${M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml`) is always required. The **user settings** file (defined in `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`) is optional. Any settings defined in the user settings take precedence over the corresponding global settings.

You can override the location of the *global and user settings* from the command line, the following example will set the global settings to *c:\global\settings.xml* and the user settings to *c:\user\settings.xml*:

```
mvn install --settings c:\user\settings.xml 
     --global-settings c:\global\settings.xml
```

Currently there is no property or means to establish what user and global settings files were used from with Maven. To access these values, you would have to modify MavenCli and/or DefaultMavenSettingsBuilder to inject the file locations into the resolved Settings object.

Comment: its would be great if we could provide multiple user's settings.xml, so we could use them with different projects for example. I know that we could use a profile. But it would be lot better if there would be a separate file. It's not possible, right?! Cheers!

Comment: I was looking for a solution to override my user settings just once without having to tamper with the file. So I just used the global file for the user settings. I.e. --settings c:\global\settings.xml this way the user file got omitted

Comment: @despot, late to the party but in a way you can through multiple profiles defined and some custom 'triggers': https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation

Comment: It always ask for pom in current folder.  "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]"

Answer (score 44):

This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:

1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user, 
                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.

   ```
             NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:

             -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
   ```
2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
                 installation). It's normally provided in 
                 ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml.

   ```
             NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:

             -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
   ```

Comment: the property is M2_HOME, not maven.home

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you set the environment variable using maven.home, it will not a problem

Answer (score 31):

The `M2_HOME` environment variable for the global one. See [Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html):

> The `settings` element in the
>   `settings.xml` file contains elements
>   used to define values which configure
>   Maven execution in various ways, like
>   the `pom.xml`, but should not be
>   bundled to any specific project, or
>   distributed to an audience. These
>   include values such as the local
>   repository location, alternate remote
>   repository servers, and authentication
>   information. There are two locations
>   where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`
> - A user's install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: If this answer is to imply that determining repository is done only by examining the environment then this is a valid answer.  I was hoping to learn of a command line switch or something that gives a definitive list of qualified paths for all settings.xml files used...  I think there is probably no such mechanism.

Comment: +1 answer, Cletus. I think it's worthwhile to mention the next line from your "Settings Reference" link: `the former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being dominant.`

Comment: The need to have a machine specific configuration to find the private repositories pains me so much. I realize this is the status quo in Java ecosystem but it leads to terribly unreproducible build setups.

Answer (score 28):

Quick and dirty method to determine if Maven is using desired settings.xml would be invalidate its xml and run some safe maven command that requires settings.xml.

If it reads **this** settings.xml then Maven reports an error: *"Error reading settings.xml..."*

Comment: While Cletus' answer was very informative, this answer is in the strictest sense more what I was looking for (given there seems to be a lack of any settings.xml file reporting mechanism in Maven itself)

Answer (score 14):

If you are debugging and wasting time like me, this will give exact details including passwords. :P

```
mvn help:effective-settings -DshowPasswords=true
```