# How do I find out which settings.xml file maven is using

Tags: maven, configuration-files

I recently changed my password and have to change my maven settings.xml file to reflect that. However, no matter what I do in the settings.xml file, the changed password just won't get picked up. Out of desperation, I ran maven with the -s switch (`mvn -s <my intended settings.xml file>`) and everything just started working. It seems to suggest that maven by default is using a "wrong" settings.xml

Is there a way for me to figure out where the settings.xml file that maven is using is located?

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261215/which-maven-settings-xml-files

Comment: Actually, The other question has no answer that I needed. nico_ekito provided with the answer that I need.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Use the Maven debug option, ie `mvn -X` :

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: /usr/java/apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.6.0_12, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_12/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-32-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/java/apache-maven-3.0.3/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/myhome/.m2/settings.xml
...
```

In this output, you can see that the settings.xml is loaded from `/home/myhome/.m2/settings.xml`.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I need some guidance. I ran the mvn -X on my system and I do not see a settings.xml listed anywhere. The output I see show Maven version 2.2.1 and user & global level plugin registry files from plugin-registry.xml. Why do I not have the settings.xml displayed and how do I get it to show?

Comment: @Elijah You should ask your own question. Reference this question in your new question.

Comment: Very helpful.  I was trying to specify "user settings" in `MAVEN_OPTS`, unfortunately this show that's not working.

Comment: Is it only my setup or is the message `Reading user settings from /home/myhome/.m2/settings.xml` only stating the *intention* to read from the file? I do get the same message after explicitly removing the file from the path. So what I get from the output is something like the effective search path for setting files but not the list of files that was actually read.

Answer (score 17):

`mvn help:effective-settings` shows the effective settings of the current environment including your location of settings.xml file.

Additionally `showPasswords=true` will help you see the passwords resolved as well if you are using environment variables.

```
mvn help:effective-settings -DshowPasswords=true
```

I had wasted a lot of time with -X option earlier and this will help you quickly solve your troubles.