# Maven multiple repositories

Tags: maven

I'm trying to set up a new repository, so I added it in my .m2/settings.xml file, but the artifact still isn't downloaded from this new repo (I don't see the 'downloading' line for this repo in the log). My profile is active by default, and I tried -U and manually removing the lastUpdated file from the .m2 folder, to no effect.

Strangely enough, if I remove the central repository from the 'repositories', it still tries to download from there, which leads me to believe the settings.xml file is not being loaded correctly.

What could I be missing ?

Comment: can you share your settings.xml file?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988814/how-do-i-find-out-which-settings-xml-file-maven-is-using

Comment: You don't need to configuration Central in your settings.xml cause it's already in Maven itself...