# Maven how to find out what settings.xml is used (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and Maven 3.3.9. I've found maven folders in different directories with settings.xml files:

- ~/.m2/ (I have cp a settings.xml file in this directory)
- /etc/maven
- /usr/share/maven/conf

...

What would be the correct place for the settings.xml file and how to find out what file Maven is using?

`mvn -X` returns No goals have been specified for this build. [...]

`mvn <goal> -X` does not even display anything about the settings.xml file

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988814/how-do-i-find-out-which-settings-xml-file-maven-is-using?rq=1

Comment: what kind of setting do you want to use?

Comment: The user settings.xml is located in $HOME/.m2/ which is usually used for configurations like repositories etc. Using /etc/maven or /usr/shared/maven/conf is usually forbidden in usual environments...