# tomcat7 maven plugin deploy fails

Tags: tomcat, maven, deployment, tomcat7

I am having trouble in deploying to remote machine with tomcat installed as aservice. 
My tomcat-users is as follows:

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="tomcat, admin, manager-gui, manager-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

My settings.xml is:

```
<settings>
<pluginGroups>
<pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
<servers>
<server>
  <id>tomcat7</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>

</servers>

</settings>
```

And my pom.xml has the following:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat7</server>
                    <url>http://localhost:8081/manager/text</url>
                    <warFile>target/editor-${project.version}.war</warFile>
                </configuration>
```

And I keep on getting the 401 Unauthorized on the output of maven console. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin

Comment: You can see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230666/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojotomcat-maven-plugin1-1deploy-default/16292897#16292897

Comment: See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230666/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojotomcat-maven-plugin1-1deploy-default/16292897#16292897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to run mvn with -x -e 
then you will see what kind of info is sending to server. my guess is that the server doesnt get username/pass. which means something wrong with the configuration file i.e:settings.xml

how does tomcat7-maven-plugin knows where settings.xml is ?

EDIT: check out this [which-maven-settings-xml-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261215/which-maven-settings-xml-files)

**elek** offered there to run mvn with -X and in the begining you see 
"Reading user settings from .user/.m2/settings.xml..

Comment: Indeed this was the issue. Settings xml was taken from different location. I assumed the correct one to be used is from C:\.m2\settings.xml, however the one from C:\users\.m2 was taken. Thx for help

Answer (score 6):

The following way works for me.

1. Please change your `pom.xml` to include

   ```
   <project>
       ...
       <build>    
           <plugins>    
           ....
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                       <server>my-tomcat</server>
                       <path>/myapp</path>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
           ...
       </build>
       ...
   </project>
   ```
2. Make sure your Tomcat 7 server have the following lines on `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml`:

   ```
   <!-- Role to manage WAR files via HTML /manager. The name should be as is! -->
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <!-- Role to manage WAR files via script like Maven. The name should be as is! -->
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>

   <!-- One user cannot have manager-gui and manager-script roles -->
   <user username="managerGui" password="managerPwd" roles="manager-gui"/>
   <user username="manager" password="managerPwd" roles="manager-script"/>
   ```
3. Configure your `USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml` to include the password.

   ```
   <settings>
       ...
       <servers>
           ...
           <server>
               <id>my-tomcat</id>
               <username>manager</username>
               <password>managerPwd</password>
           </server>
       </servers>

   </settings>
   ```
4. Deploy using `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`

Read more on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

`mvn tomcat7:redeploy -Dtomcat.username=tomcatscript -Dtomcat.password=s3cret`

works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all the roles in the tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
```

HIH

Comment: remove the trailing spaces in the roles="..."

Comment: can you connect to http://localhost:8081/manager/text ? do you see FAIL - Unknown command /text ? Have you the UserDatabase configured in the server.xml ?