# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat7

i am trying to do **mvn tomcat:deploy** and i came across with the error

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project appanalytix: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project appanalytix: Cannot invoke
Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
```

in **maven\conf\settings.xml**

```
<server>
<id>TomcatServer</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>admin</password>
</server>
```

in **tomcat-7.0.39\conf\tomcat-users**

```
 <tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<configuration>
    <mode>war</mode>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
    <server>TomcatServer</server>
    <path>/appanalytix</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

i have tried using **/text** and **/html** [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin/4553021#comment-5868038)  but that doesn't worked ,please help me to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must be aware of the move of the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/) to the [apache software foundation](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html)
Second you shouldn't put configuration stuff into maven/conf/settings.xml you should use the users settings.xml file HOME/.m2/settings.xml instead.

Apart from the above you should use the following URL for accessing Tomcat:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

Comment: I had a problem because I had not add `/html` at the end of `http://localhost:8080/manager`.

Comment: Did not work for me (same configuration). This is not a deterministic solution.

Answer (score 24):

The following way works for me.

1. Please change your `pom.xml` to include

   ```
   <project>
       ...
       <build>    
           <plugins>    
           ....
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                       <server>my-tomcat</server>
                       <path>/myapp</path>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
           ...
       </build>
       ...
   </project>
   ```
2. Make sure your Tomcat 7 server have the following lines on `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml`:

   ```
   <!-- Role to manage WAR files via HTML /manager. The name should be as is! -->
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <!-- Role to manage WAR files via script like Maven. The name should be as is! -->
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>

   <!-- One user cannot have manager-gui and manager-script roles -->
   <user username="managerGui" password="managerPwd" roles="manager-gui"/>
   <user username="manager" password="managerPwd" roles="manager-script"/>
   ```
3. Configure your `USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml` to include the password.

   ```
   <settings>
       ...
       <servers>
           ...
           <server>
               <id>my-tomcat</id>
               <username>manager</username>
               <password>managerPwd</password>
           </server>
       </servers>

   </settings>
   ```
4. Deploy using `mvn tomcat7:redeploy`

Read more on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive and deterministic answer (which should be the accepted answer).

Comment: @sancho21 running `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` on Mac OS X Yosemite gives an error with version `2.0` of the plugin. Version `2.2` works just fine with `tomcat7:redeploy`.

Comment: I have Tomcat 8 server and `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` still works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution worked. I did one petty mistake of not starting Apache Tomcat Server.

Apart from this, make user that you do appropriate entry in maven/conf/setting.xml within  tag:-

```
<server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

In Apache Tomcat 7 tomcat-users.xml, following line should be added within

```
<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
     <role rolename="manager-script"/>
      <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
      <role rolename="manager-status"/>
      <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
      <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="standard,manager,admin,manager-gui,manager-script,tomcat" />
```

In Pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8888/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>$ReplaceWithWarFileName$</path>
        <update>true</update>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A solution that worked for me was in the Run options :

   1_ Maven Install

   2_ Maven Build

Answer (score -1):

A solution which worked in my case is:

1. Go to the module having Main class.
2. Right click on pom.xml under this module.
3. Select "Run Maven" -> "UpdateSnapshots"