# Amazon AWS, deploy war to tomcat 8 with maven

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I'm using codehaus.mojo library and trying to deploy my war file to the server. I did it like in some tutorial, but i dont know is it should work for amazon.

I've added user:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="test" password="test" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

edited settings.xml:

```
<server>
        <id>mytomcat</id>
        <username>test</username>
        <password>test</password>
</server>
```

added to pom.xml plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://35.164.242.196/manager</url>
                    <server>mytomcat</server>
                    <path>/test</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have error like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project springwebapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Error writing to server -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project springwebapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1567)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:604)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
        ... 23 more
```

I've already checked webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml for max-file-size, increased it, although my war have less than 47mb.

Comment: Can you access the manager from a browser or curl?

Comment: @jingx, yes i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added one more user with role "manager-script" to tomcat-users. Of course i've edited settings.xml according to new role, it's work!

P.S. for reload EXISTING project use redeploy comand.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292897/5651564