# MAVEN 407 Authentication Exception- Taking username null while building project

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a maven project. Following are specifications of system and maven version:

> ```
> Apache Maven 3.5.0,
> Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle,
> Corporation Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252,
> OS name:    "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family:    "windows"
> ```

on running `mvn install` command I am getting following error.

> [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata
>   com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-kendo-ui:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>   from/to sonatype-snapshots
>   (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/): Error
>   transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL:
>   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/wicket-jquery-ui/wicket-kendo-ui/8.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>   from
>   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/wicket-jquery-ui/wicket-kendo-ui/8.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>   with proxyInfo ProxyInfo{host='', userName='null', port=,
>   type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}

I am working behind proxy so I have added following mapping in settings.xml which is inside %MAVEN_HOME%\conf:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <host>proxyhost</host>
      <port>proxyport</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

even after adding username and password in settings.xml it is considering username as null and throwing 407 authentication error. Its causing problem to build the project. Please help to resolve this.

**Update:**

variables:

> MAVEN_HOME=D:\Apache\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0
>   M2_HOME=D:\Apache\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0

Complete mvn -version :

> Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426;
>   2017-04-04T01:09:06+05:30) Maven home:
>   D:\Apache\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin.. Java version: 1.8.0_121,
>   vendor: Oracle Corporation  Java home: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre Default locale: en_IN,  platform encoding:
>   Cp1252 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64",
>   family:"windows"

Comment: can you share complete details of `mvn -version` and the `%MAVEN_HOME%\` configured by you.

Comment: `from/to sonatype-snapshots´ Maven is trying to transfer an artifcat from/your snapshot-repository. Make sure your credentials for the snapshot repository (tag `<distributionManagement>`) are correct  - meaning there is an <server> entry in your settings.xml with same ID as your snapshot repository and providing username, password

Comment: @nullpointer updated details in question

Comment: @bish yes credentials are correct.

Comment: Could you try figuring out which settings.xml is being used by maven. Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261215/maven-command-to-determine-which-settings-xml-file-maven-is-using

Comment: It is using the same settings.xml where I have added proxy. Already checked with -X.