# .m2 repo downloading in Undefined path. ie: D: drive

Tags: java, maven

Maven Repo  .m2 is downloading in D: drive insted of C: user:.m2 in Eclispe build (Problem is only on clean install)

exsting repo is not updating instead it will download new .m2 in D: drive even though path is defined in setting.xml.

Comment: You may have multiple settings applied in your computer. You could check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261215/maven-command-to-determine-which-settings-xml-file-maven-is-using

Comment: i did build using eclipse. while doing maven update new repo was downloaded in c:user:userid:m2 , but while doing clean install new repo is downloading under d: .m2